# Aparecer botão de ajuda quando a caixa de texto for selecionada (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estou a um tempo procurando, sobre como colocar um botão de ajuda que só aparece ao lado da caixa de texto, quando a mesma for selecionada. Tem algum modo de fazer isso no c#?

Assim deveria ficar quando a caixa de texto fosse selecionada, ou seja, apareceria o "i" para fornecer algumas informações de como preencher essa determinada caixa de texto

[image]

E assim é como deveria ficar se a caixa não estivesse selecionada, porém eu não sei como fazer isso

[image]

Comment: Está utilizando WPF/WinForms/UWP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solução passa por criar uma extensão do controlo `TextBox` e adicionar-lhe o botão. Depois é só subscrever os eventos `GotFocus` e `LostFocus` para mostrar ou esconder o botão:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyUserControls
{
    public class InfoTextBox : TextBox
    {
        protected override void OnCreateControl()
        {
            base.OnCreateControl();

            Button button = new Button()
            {
                Name = "btnInfo",
                Text = "!",
                Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 6f),
                Size = new System.Drawing.Size(20, this.Height - 4),
                Location = new System.Drawing.Point(this.Width - 24, 0),
                Margin = new Padding(2),
                Visible = false
            };

            button.Click += (s, e) =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Clicou!!");
            };

            this.Controls.Add(button);

            this.GotFocus += (s, e) => { button.Visible = true; };
            this.LostFocus += (s, e) => { button.Visible = false; };
        }
    }
}
```

No `Form` basta utilizar este controlo ao invés do nativo e, voilá!